# odroidxu4 changing default uart2 to uart0

Tags: linux, odroid

previously thank you for watching this post.

I have tried to run linux on odroidxu4 and of course the logs are written through uart2 (this uart seems default in odroidxu4)

But what I'm trying to do is changing the linux to write the logs with uart0 not the uart2.

I tried to change the default uart port from 2 to 0 by modifying the code in common/serial.c in u-boot

and also tried to change the menuconfig in linux like below :

1. kernel hacking => Kernel low-level debugging functions
2. choose in "Kernel low-level debugging port" to "Use S3C UART 0 for low-level debug"

But it didn't work.

please let me know if there's another way to change the dafault uart from 2 to 0 that i missed

thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will change the location of this question to Unix & Linx STack Exchange.